# D3.JS how to load 3 csv files and change data on line chart with button click event?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am attempting to create a line chart of 3 datasets, each dataset represents a gun in Call of Duty Warzone and I'm trying to visualize what the best time to kill is over a 0-60 meter range.

I'm having an issue where I am reading in 3 csv files, each one represents a category of a gun in the game. I want to change the graph lines with a button between each of the gun categories.

**Script**

````
var smgCsv = "smgs.csv";
var lmgCsv = "lmgs.csv";

var fileData = null;

function renderData(dataIndex) {
  if(fileData == null) {
    return;
  }
  document.getElementById("rifles").data = fileData[dataIndex];
  console.log(fileData[dataIndex]);
}

Promise.all([
  d3.csv(assultCsv),
  d3.csv(smgCsv),
  d3.csv(lmgCsv)
]).then(function(data) {
  fileData = data; ```


<main>
      
    <div id="rifles">
      <h1>Call of Duty Warzone</h1>
      <h1>Time to kill Rating</h1>
      <div class="buttons">
        <input class="but" type="button" value="Assult Rifles" id="rifles.csv"  onclick="renderData([0]);"/>
        <input class="but" type="button" value="Sub Machine Guns" id="smgs.csv" onclick="renderData([1]);" />
        <input class="but" type="button" value="Light Machine Guns" id="lmgs.csv" onclick="renderData([2]);" />
        </div>
  
    </div>
    </main>
````

I created a function called `renderData` that takes a parameter of dataIndex. This function is in the button's attributes within the HTML with `onclick`. With each button representing a value index for the promise array.

I also created a variable to represent the data called `fileData`, I want to make this equal to the data array to select which csv file to render when the appropriate button is clicked. However `fileData` keeps returning the full array with the 3 datasets, therefore the graph is not being drawn.

So in short I need to get the index number from the onclick function to select `data[0], data[1] or data[2]`.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Bind `renderData` to the buttons at runtime.
If you use **D3 V6**:

```
d3.selectAll('.buttons > .but').on('click', (e, i) => renderData(i));
```

For **V5** and earlier:

```
d3.selectAll('.buttons > .but').on('click', (i) => renderData(i));
```